# Launchd Multicast Socket Listener

Tags: macos, network, launchd

I'm not sure if I've just missed some documentation or not, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set up a `launchd` agent that can be triggered whenever a datagram is received within a multicast group.

What I'd like to know is what a `launchd` plist should look like to provide a simple datagram listener that is bound to a multicast group.

Here's what I've been trying:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>foo.bar</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/foo/bar</string>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Listeners</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SockType</key>
            <string>dgram</string>
            <key>SockServiceName</key>
            <string>12345</string>
            <key>SockFamily</key>
            <string>IPv4</string>
            <key>MulticastSocket</key>
            <string>224.0.0.253</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But it just generates `getaddrinfo` errors ("nodename nor servname provided, or not known"). Removing the multicast group to just setup a UDP port seems to work fine, but I don't really want to have to hard code an IP address or local DNS.

Are there any good examples of how to create a multicast listening launch agent or daemon using `launchd`? Or am I missing some other step, or misunderstanding what data I should be entering for a multicast group?

Comment: What is a multicast listening launch agent? And a datagram listener? Although I have created numerous launch agents, I have never seen these terms/jargon.

Comment: You can create launch agents with a list of sockets, if they receive a message on one of these then the program is launchd with the message on standard input. Multicasting is UDP (datagrams) where a message is simply sent out to all machines in the network with no need to connect to them first, and any that choose to can respond.

Comment: how may i test a working launchd Multicast Socket Listener daemon means how may i invoke such a datagram?

Comment: You can test sending of a UDP message by doing something like `echo 'My message' | nc -uw 1 localhost 6000` to send the message to a service listening to port 6000 on your local machine. Not sure if `nc` supports sending multicast messages (I don't see an option) but it lets you test when sending directly to a single machine.

Answer (score 1):

I set this one up using [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>foo/bar</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/foo/bar</string>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Sock1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>MulticastGroup</key>
            <string>224.0.0.253</string>
            <key>SockFamily</key>
            <string>IPv4</string>
            <key>SockProtocol</key>
            <string>UDP</string>
            <key>SockServiceName</key>
            <string>12345</string>
            <key>SockType</key>
            <string>dgram</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Were you able to verify this in any way? I've given the same basic file a try, simply using `cat` as the program and redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` (using the appropriate plist keys) but it's not producing any output. Instead I'm getting a bunch of "no such file or directory" errors from `execv()`. I've tried replacing `cat` with a simple shell script and confirmed the correct path, but that won't work either.